# Swift - Operator Overload - Multiplication for CGFloat

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, operator-overloading

So I have something like this in my code:

```
let padding = mySprite1.size.height/2
let margin = 1.2
```

Then in a function, I try to multiply them like:

```
newSprite.position = CGPointMake(x: 0 + (padding * margin), y: 0)
```

But it errors saying no binary overloading... So I try to overload them like this:

```
public func * (a: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return a * b
}
```

But it errors, I even followed the exact way RayWenderlich overloads his +.

I put my method in the GameScene, does it need to be placed somewhere else?

Comment: What type is margin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `margin` is a `Double`. Try this:

```
newSprite.position = CGPoint(x: padding * CGFloat(margin), y: 0)
```

Comment: oops... silly mistake. How did I miss that! Thanks for posting. I've changed `let margin = 1.2` to `let margin = CGFloat(1.2)` and it's working.

Comment: you can also do `let margin:CGFloat = 1.2`

Comment: or just `(padding * 1.2)` ;-) kidding!

Comment: I have 80+ calls with the same margin space, so I figured it would be easier to use a variable I can just change once if I need to, instead of over 80 times :)